# After sleeping DisplayPort loses sound on Surface Book

Tags: windows-10, audio, sleep, displayport, microsoft-surface

I have sound coming through my connected monitor to my Surface Book via the Display Port. After a restart all is good. But if my computer sleeps for too long (lower power state) and resumes, monitor syncs fine but audio device is not available.

Is there a why to restart the display port service? An unplug plug doesn't work, but a whole computer restart does, which I want to avoid if I can just find the specific process that needs to restart.

On Windows 10 Creators Update. Was the on Windows 10, anniversary update seemed to lose audio less and sometime got it back with unplug plug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

1. Go to Device Manager
2. Sound, video and game controllers
3. Select Intel(R) Display Audio
4. Disable Device, Confirm
5. Enable device

The monitor sound is then available from the speaker icon in the notification area again.

Comment: Thanks, for me it was the NVIDIA High Definition Audio